# Open Facebook Share in a modal pop up window or standard pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to get my Facebook share button to open up in a modal window (a bit like lightbox opens images), but so far all I can get it to do is open in a brand new window, which I don't want.

I've noticed that Twitter opens in a small pop up window, which would be ideal if I can't get the Facebook Share window to open as a modal window. But again I can't seem to get the Facebook window to do this.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: No, you can’t do this. If the user is not logged in to Facebook already, then FB has to present them with the login dialog – and that can only be opened in a top window instance, not in any kind of frames, for security reasons.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<a class="fb-share" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.manojyadav.co.in" target="_blank">
    Share on Facebook
</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fb-share').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'fbShareWindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 275) + ', left=' + ($(window).width() / 2 - 225) + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/y7YyE/1)**

Example Using Facebook JavaScript SDK

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="fb-share">Share on Facebook</a>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

JavaScript & jQuery

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '409742669131720',  // Change appId 409742669131720 with your Facebook Application ID
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        cookie: true
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fb-share').click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Manoj Yadav',
            link: 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/2502457/manoj-yadav',
            picture: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/119a8e2d668922c32083445b01189d67',
            description: 'Manoj Yadav from Mumbai, India'
        });
    });
});
```

To use the Facebook JavaScript SDK you will need to create a `Facebook App` and replace `appId` `409742669131720` with your `appId`

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/y7YyE/1)**

Comment: I do not want the popup window.
 Bootstrap modal box in facebook share

Comment: In Bootstrap modal box remote content is only possible using `iframe` but Facebook share will not work in iframe because Facebook set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Comment: It's using `Facebook JavaScript SDK`, answer updated

Comment: User needs to authorized the app to see `FB Dialog` otherwise popup will open

Comment: When i share link on my own facebook wall it showing following error 

"An error occurred. Please try later"

Comment: @RakeshJogani Please make sure you have setup the Facebook App properly like appId and url

Comment: @ManojYadav 

I setup facebook app with proper url when i share  link using Administrators,Developers,Testers and Insights Users account it is working fine. But user come from outside (external user) it is showing error 

"An error occurred. Please try later"

Any advance setting in facebook app to share outside user share post it own wall.

Comment: @RakeshJogani that means your app is in development mode, You can make it live by click on `Yes` in `Status & Review` review tab below app settings

Comment: This makes a pop-up but it's on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 18):

I think I have found a better solution, whereby you inject the pop up styling into onclick="".

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/artchibald/pen/OXGOVm

This solution is much less work.

```
<a target="_blank" OnClick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=0,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=600,height=250'); return false;" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fem%2F4881-01%2F&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fem%2F4881-01%2Fimg%2Fmercedes-maybach.png&title=title+here&description=Your+description">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="57" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the easier method..I just have one question does it have any drawback compared to the conventional method used in the accepted answer?

Comment: I used this on a project and it is cross browser compatible so there are no drawbacks in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot..it helped a lot!

Answer (score 16):

A nice and working solution for Facebook, Twitter, Google plus, LinkedIn...
Found [HERE](http://kodex.pierros.fr/javascript/popup-partage-reseaux-sociaux-javascript/) (in french)
Works great in Wordpress also (Merci Pierro ( si tu passes par ici ;) )

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED&t=TITLE" class="share facebook" data-network="facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=URLENCODED&text=TITLE" class="share twitter" data-network="twitter">Share on Twitter</a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=URLENCODED" class="share google" data-network="google">Share on Google+</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=URLENCODED&title=TITLE&source=COMPANY" class="share linkedin" data-network="linkedin">Share on LinkedIn</a>
```

JS

```
$('a.share').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $link   = $(this);
var href    = $link.attr('href');
var network = $link.attr('data-network');

var networks = {
    facebook : { width : 600, height : 300 },
    twitter  : { width : 600, height : 254 },
    google   : { width : 515, height : 490 },
    linkedin : { width : 600, height : 473 }
};

var popup = function(network){
    var options = 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,';
    window.open(href, '', options+'height='+networks[network].height+',width='+networks[network].width);
}

popup(network);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain where you got the dimensions (width & height) from?

Comment: I think you should change the networks variable (width & height) according to your site. I use these one displayed here for my site and hide social share for screen smaller than 480px with media queries.